# How do I dynamicly connect to different devices on their COM ports with the same function?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I have two devices that each have their usb-serial connector. The usb-serial connection gives access to 3 COM ports for communication to different chips on each device.
I want to create a function `initialise()` that automatically scans and hooks up to the COM ports of the device which isnt in use yet.

I currently have the following, but it fails to hook up with the second device when I run the function twice and I am stuck right now so I need a clever suggestion.

```
def initialise():
    PORTMAPPINGWIN = {'fwmain': ('COM8','COM12','COM4'),
                    'fwutil': ('COM9','COM13','COM5'),
                    'fwcif': ('COM10','COM14','COM6')}
    PORTMAPPINGMAC = {'fwmain': ('/dev/tty.usbserial-000013FAB','/dev/tty.usbserial-12345B'),
                    'fwutil': ('/dev/tty.usbserial-000013FAC','/dev/tty.usbserial-12345C'),
                    'fwcif': ('/dev/tty.usbserial-000013FAD','/dev/tty.usbserial-12345D')}

    if os.name == 'nt':
        _portmap = PORTMAPPINGWIN
    else:
        _portmap = PORTMAPPINGMAC

    _available = []

    _n = len(_portmap['fwmain'])
    for portaddress in range(_n):
        for termname in _portmap.keys():
            usb = _portmap[termname][portaddress]
            try:
                _ser = serial.Serial(usb, 115200)
                _ser.close()
                _available.append(usb)
            except serial.SerialException:
                pass


    _available.sort()
    if _available != [] and _available != None:
        if _available[0] == 'COM10': #TODO use a regex instead to replace all COM5 instances with COM05 so that we can sort properly list('COM5').insert(re.search(r'(?<=COM)\d', 'COM5').start(), '0')
            if len(_available) < 4:
                _available.insert(3, _available.pop(0))
            elif len(_available) < 7:
                _available.insert(6, _available.pop(0))
            elif len(_available) < 10:
                _available.insert(9, _available.pop(0))

    print([port for port in _available])

    if len(_available) > 3:
        _available = _available[:3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. I changed `except serial.SerialException:` to `except Exception:` and now it works fine.
Thank you me.

I think this is a cool procedure for anyone who want to start the same script on multiple attached devices. And if you dont want to pre-specify the COM ports that the device is listed at, you could just replace

```
for portaddress in range(_n):
    for termname in _portmap.keys():
        usb = _portmap[termname][portaddress]
```

with `for usb in range(255): usb = 'COM' + str(usb)` or something like that..